# C# EF Migrations don't create table

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core

It seems like I kinda broke my project. When I use e.g. `add-migration initial` to add a new migration, it generates a migration file in the project folder which looks correct, but I dont see it in my solution (in VS 22). When I try to update the database, it just generates the `__EFMigrationsHistory` -table, but everything else is missing and the command ends with `No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.`

It feels like i broke the whole migration thing. Does someone has an idea on this?

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.1">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql" Version="6.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: Check the `csproj` file to see if it excludes the migration folder from the compilation.

Comment: @Eldar The Migrations folder isnt even specifically mentioned in the .csproj. Do I need to explicitly exclude it from compiling?

Comment: No, the thing you can do is press the `Show All Files` button in your Solution Explorer then locate and right-click on the mutations folder then select include.

Comment: @Eldar Wow, that really fixed the whole issue. Thank you so much. :)